# How do I move github repo from client folder to root folder?

Tags: node.js, git, github

I was trying to stage and commit changes for a project in VS code but I could not see any changes in source control. I realized that I made a github repository of "client" folder but I wanted to make github repository of the "estate" folder which has "client" folder in it.

How can I correct this while preserving git history?

[image]

I tried `mv .git ..` but got this error " mv : Access to the path 'C:\Users\jutika patil\estate\client.git' is denied."

Comment: Hmm, technically, moving the `.git` folder and then subsequently committing everything should work. I am guessing that VS Code has locked some files in the `.git` directory, preventing you from moving it. Have you tried moving it while VS Code is closed?